# How to filter entities subresources with the Api Platform filters

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

In our API we need to show only filtered data. Example:

Deal entity has a one-to-many relation with Manager entity (so $managers is a subresource for the Deal). I need to filter all deal items with a special value of for example surname of the Manager. I've made a SearchFilter on the manager's surname Deal.

```
@ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"managers.surname": "exact"})
```

It works as expected, but the result collection of deals contains unfiltered managers.

As I investigated, a query for filtering deals contains needed condition, but only in the subquery.

```
#Doctrine query dump goes here
SELECT ... FROM deal 
# bunch of JOINS here
WHERE deal.id IN (
SELECT d.id FROM deal d
JOIN manager m ... 
# bunch of JOINS here
WHERE m.surname = :surname
)
# but we need "WHERE m.surname = :surname" condition on the level up also
```

How can I copy it to the upper level? Maybe there is a proper way to deal with my issue? I've found a same problem Github [issue](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/424) but without any solution there.

Comment: Also, this issue affects my https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/944

Comment: I've created an issue related to this question. https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2253